# How can my injected service (LoggingService) is working without @Injectable being used?

Tags: javascript, angular

im trying to inject a service (LoggingService) into another service (AccountService) so accountsService definitely need @Injectable to inject it proberly..... the problem is i have just add it to the constructor without adding @Injectable and it's working as it should ....... how can my app run though without using @Injectable?

```
import { LoggingService } from "./logging.service";

export class AccountsService {
    constructor(private loggingService: LoggingService) {}

    accounts = [{
            name: 'Master Account',
            status: 'active'
        },
        {
            name: 'Testaccount',
            status: 'inactive'
        },
        {
            name: 'Hidden Account',
            status: 'unknown'
        }
    ];

    addAccount(newAccount: {name: string, status: string}) {
        this.accounts.push(newAccount);
        this.loggingService.loggingStatusChange(newAccount.status);
    }

    updateStatus(id: number, status: string) {
        this.accounts[id].status = status;
        this.loggingService.loggingStatusChange(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Do you have a Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**As long as you are not inject or use**  **`AccountsService`** **to any component visible by your app**, it will work just fine ( what i mean by saying visible is that it been whether 'imported / declared / provided' in the `@NgModule()` class decorator).

**If you already used your `AccountsService`** somewhere and your app not yelling **`error`** at you. Then it probably provided in the `@NgModule({})` somewhere in your app. Otherwise there no way it can work.